# htaccess multi language site with sub directories, and default 301

Tags: .htaccess, localization, multilingual, http-status-code-301

I am having some issues setting up my htaccess to allow multiple languages utilising the sub directory method eg:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/
http://www.domain.com/sw/
http://www.domain.com/ie/
```

Also to complicate things, the project isn't currently live, its on a dev server. For example, **I am currently accessing the project at:**

```
http://dev.domain.com/devname/projectname/
```

And I want the above to **automatically 301 redirect to:**

```
http://dev.domain.com/devname/projectname/en/
```

**Here is my htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# MULTI LANGUAGE SUB DIRECTORY
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|sw)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [R=301,L]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite rules
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

## CASE STUDIES ##
RewriteRule ^casestudies/([^/\.]+).html$ index.php?controller=contents&method=viewCasestudy&link=$1 [L,QSA]

## PRODUCTS ##
RewriteRule ^products/([^/\.]+).html$ index.php?controller=contents&method=viewProduct&link=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z{2}]+)(/)?$ index.php?controller=contents&method=viewHome&lang=$1 [L,QSA] # Default load
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php?controller=contents&method=viewHome [L,QSA] # Default load
```

**The above will actually redirect to:**

```
http://dev.domain.com/home/webserver_dir/devname/projectname/en/
```

..and if I use RewriteBase it seems to just goto...

```
http://dev.domain.com/en/
```

**So my question:** How do I get the language URLs working correctly relative to the directory its in on my dev server, and then ideally will work when it goes live without any environment specific rules.

**Bonus question:** Do I need to add the ([a-z{2}]+) bit in front of all my subsequent rewrite rules or can I have a catch all that will effect all further rules?

### EDIT -----------------------------

*I have reduced it down to the following as suggested...*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /devname/projectname/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|sw)(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?controller=contents&method=viewHome&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA] # Default load
```

... but now its redirecting to `http://dev.domain.com/devname/projectname/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/`, any ideas?

Comment: What is DOCUMENT_ROOT on your `dev.domain.com`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried the answer in the following link? It should do what you're trying to achieve.

[Endless Redirect Loop by htaccess rules multi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474511/endless-redirect-loop-by-htaccess-rules-multi-language)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   

# empty url -> redirect to en/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(en|de)
RewriteRule ^$ en/ [R=301,L]

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/de' -> redirect to /en/ or /de/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|de)$  $1/ [R=301,L]

# now all urls have en/ de/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1&%{query_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: This solution will only work for root directories, not for inner sub folders .. e.g. **xyz.com/test/en** will not work

Answer (score 4):

## If .htaccess must not change

Change your `<VirtualHost>` configuration for your *DEV* server project as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.domain.com
    ServerAlias project.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/webserver_dir/devname/projectname"
</VirtualHost>
```

These changes would typically go in your *httpd-vhosts.conf* file. Your *.htaccess* files would now have

```
RewriteBase /
```

to mark *root* as your *base* directory for both your *development* and *live* servers.

If you're trying to version your projects or test multiple projects on the same *dev* host, then you would have to incorporate the naming scheme into the domain names instead of the URL path. For example,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev1.domain.com
    ServerAlias project1.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/webserver_dir/dev1/project1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev2.domain.com
    ServerAlias project2.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/webserver_dir/dev2/project2"
</VirtualHost>
```

The bottom line is that you can not have the same *.htaccess* file rules working untouched with different deployment directories unless you resort to *mod-rewrite* way of *if-else* mumbo jumbo which would just be added clutter once you've gone live.

For the rules to work transparently, Apache must only see and apply the rules on what's going *live* (the content that comes after `/devX/projectX/` directories) which is what shifting the `DocumentRoot` does here for us.

## If minimal mods to .htaccess are okay

Not everyone has access to Apache's *.conf* files. Certain hosts out-rightly reject requests to modify them. Which is why, if they have at least kept *mod-rewrite* enabled, a lot of website's settings can be tinkered with. One of them is to use `RewriteBase` to handle the different deployment directories.

So, if you keep `RewriteBase /` on *live* but change it to `RewriteBase /devX/projectX/` for *development*, most of your `RewriteRule`s should work as is. So, `/devname/projectname/` should correctly redirect to `/devname/projectname/en/`.

---

Your use of `([a-z{2}]+)` is incorrect. You probably meant `([a-z]{2})` to capture exactly two letters. If you meant to capture two or more, it would become `([a-z]{2,})`. So, your *default load* rewrite would become

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?controller=contents&method=viewHome&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA] # Default load
```

You're correct to assume that you would need this regex for all subsequent rules or they would fail to match. So, your `RewriteRule` for `casestudies` won't work. A simpler way to not care about the language prefix is to drop the `^` start of URL path anchor as

```
RewriteRule /casestudies/([^/\.]+).html$ index.php?controller=contents&method=viewCasestudy&link=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule /products/([^/\.]+).html$ index.php?controller=contents&method=viewProduct&link=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Your last `RewriteRule` matching `^(/)?$` isn't required because you're already doing a `301` redirect for all URLs with no language directory prefix to `/en/$1` above, which should ideally be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|sw)(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise, `/en` would get redirected as well to `/en/en`.

Comment: great answer, I'll use the second section, although now its giving me recurring redirect issues even though I entered the rules as you described. I have updated my question and simplified the htaccess

Comment: @Horse My apologies. I was away (celebrating Diwali - a big festival here in India :)) and couldn't respond to your comments. Let me take a look at your updates and I'll suggest a solution in a short while. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: no problem, happy Diwali :) and I will look forward to your response

Comment: @Horse The `301` redirect needs to be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 [R=301,L]`. This makes sure that we redirect without prepend-ing project path to the URL.

Comment: this works fine as is (eg for the live server), but on the dev server, changing the 301 to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/devname/projectname/en/$1 [R=301,L]` it still gets stuck in a redirect loop :(

Comment: The `RewriteRule` would remain the same on both `live` and `dev` server since the project path should never be appended to **external** redirects. Except for the website domain, the site structure (what comes after the host like `/en`) should remain the same at the client/browser side for both `live` and `dev`. It's only the **internal** redirects (not visible to clients) that would resolve differently based on the deployment directories that are different on `live` and `dev` but that is already being taken care of by the `RewriteBase`.