# Localize URL's with ui-router and angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I am using ui-router for routing and angular-translate for translations. What i would like to achieve is having the selected language bind to the url like so:

```
www.mydomain.com/en/
www.mydomain.com/ru/
www.mydomain.com/en/about
www.mydomain.com/ru/about
```

and it will respond accordingly.

Tried to look for examples, but did not find anything.
If someone implemented similar solution, i would love to hear how you did it.

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use something along these lines:

**CoffeeScript**

```
angular.module('app')
.config([
  '$stateProvider'
  ($stateProvider) ->
    $stateProvider.state 'app',
      abstract: true
      url: '/{locale}'
    $stateProvider.state 'app.root',
      url: ''
    $stateProvider.state 'app.root.about',
      url: '/about'
])
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app').config([
  '$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/{locale}'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('app.root', {
      url: ''
    });
    return $stateProvider.state('app.root.about', {
      url: '/about'
    });
  }
]);
```

With this, you can inject `$stateParams` into your controller and get access to the locale there:

**CoffeeScript**

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('appCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$stateParams'
  ($scope, $stateParams) ->
    $scope.locale = $stateParams.locale
])
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app').controller('appCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    return $scope.locale = $stateParams.locale;
  }
]);
```

Or, if you want to affect the whole page automatically, use the `$stateChangeStart` event in an application controller or similar:

**CoffeeScript**

```
$scope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) ->
  $translate.use(toParams.locale)
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  $translate.use(toParams.locale);
});
```

Note that if you're using angular-translate v1.x you should use `$translate.uses` instead of `$translate.use`.

Comment: Ah, yes - this seems to have changed between v1.x and v2.x and I'm using v1.x at the moment -- I'll make a note in the answer, thanks.

Comment: I want the url to have a language code when user navigates to the main page of the webpage by `domain.com` -> `domain.com/en/`

To do so I need to detect user language first and then add `{locale}` params to the url. 
Is there a good solution for it?

Comment: see my question and my solution in the update if it is still relevant :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601801/angularjs-routing-in-multilanguage-app

Comment: Hi, @mjtko How can I achieve the same thing using angular 12?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is valid only if you want to have URLs of the below format:

`domain.com/{locale}/about`

hence:

`domain.com/en/about
 domain.com/mt/about`

Recently we were required to implement translations for the full URL, therefore:

`domain.com/{locale}/{about}`

where `{about}` is translated in the respective language:

`domain.com/en/about
 domain.com/mt/fuqna`

I don't know if the below approach is the best one, however it does work.

For starters, the first difference is that we set up ui-router states to be generated dynamically using a service which retrieves the routes from a JSON file. This is done similarly to @ChrisT's answer in: [Angular - UI Router - programmatically add states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866387/angular-ui-router-programmatically-add-states)

```
module.service("routingService", ["$http", function($http) {

    self.get = function(options) {           
        return self.getByLocale({
            market: options.urlMarketCode
        });
    };

    self.getByLocale = function(options) {
        var market = options.market;

        // loads the different .json files based on the different market values passed, ex: routes-en.json
        var configurationKey = "routes-" + market;

        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: configurationKey + ".json",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data) {
                return response.data;
            }
            return undefined;
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    };

    return self;
}]);
```

We would then consume the above `routingService` in the `run` block of the application:

```
// run the module and register the state change handler
angular.module("sportsbook-app").run(["$state", "$rootScope", "routingService", "stateService",
    function ($state, $rootScope, routingService, stateService) {
        // retrieve the routing heirarchy from file
        routingService.get({
            urlMarketCode: $rootScope.language
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                // add the routes to the $stateProvider
                stateService.generate(response);
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

And finally the `stateService` simply parses the JSON file and creates the routing hierarchy using ChrisT's runtimeStates.addState.

I will try to include a working demo in the near future.

Credits also go to @karl-agius.

Comment: HI, I interested in this solution. Could you please point a link or article which describe this solution in detail? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Seto I tried to include a plunker that simulates this scenario however I had to scale it down slightly. **Note that I am not sure if I would recommend this approach.**

If you also want to include changing of language without refreshing you will probably need to listen to the `$stateChangeStart` events and update the states from there.

**Code**:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r51UEZ)

**Demo URLs**:
[http://run.plnkr.co/Fxo80MbXmuLfdG5c/#/en](http://run.plnkr.co/Fxo80MbXmuLfdG5c/#/en)
[http://run.plnkr.co/Fxo80MbXmuLfdG5c/#/sv](http://run.plnkr.co/Fxo80MbXmuLfdG5c/#/en)

Comment: Hello @KevinFarrugia for en language i don't want to add locale. i.e.
en => domain.com/about
mt => domain.com/mt/fuqna
what can i do? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Hi @AshishMehta unfortunately I have not worked on this project (or similar) for a very long time and am not updated with the latest solutions; however I would assume that it is possible to have a default value for ```{locale}```

Answer (score 2):

I've written a blog post on the exact matter:
http://fadeit.dk/post/angular-translate-ui-router-seo

Comment: Thanks for the link to your post @ozooner. you can check out the app i have built: www.azorly.com

Comment: Please quote the relevant part of the post in your answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

For people that would like to include the URL using ngRoute (I came here googling for exactly that), I've implemented it as follows.

(1) In my `.htaccess` I caught all URLs without a language subdomain and redirected it to the default (fr in my case). The only real downside is that I have to specify every language manually.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570572/htaccess-multi-language-site-with-sub-directories-and-default-301/19902914#19902914
# Add language to URL - redirect to default if missing    

RewriteBase /   

# empty url -> redirect to nl/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(nl|fr)
RewriteRule ^$ fr/ [R=301,L]

# url is ONLY '/nl' or '/fr' -> redirect to /nl/ or /fr/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(nl|fr)$  $1/ [R=301,L]

# now all urls have nl/ fr/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(nl|fr)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1&%{query_STRING} [L]
```

(2) In my Angular project's `config` block I then simply parsed the URL to get the current language.

```
config.$inject = ['$translateProvider', '$windowProvider'];

function config($translateProvider, $windowProvider) {

    var $window,
        language;

        $window  = $windowProvider.$get();
        language = $window.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, '');

    //////

    $translateProvider
      .useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'translations/',
        suffix: '.json'
          })
      .useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitizeParameters')
      .preferredLanguage( language )
}
```

(3) In order to get the language in my HTML files I also added it to the `$rootScope`.

```
run.$inject = ['$window', '$rootScope'];

function run($window, $rootScope ) {
    $rootScope.language = $window.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, '');
}
```