# Ionic nested views with infinite level

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile app with Ionic and AngularJS. I have a scenario like this:

A  Category has got a number of sub categories.

Example given: If you click on any category it shows its sub categories. If you click on any sub category it shows its sub categories and so on.

I tried with changing url by passing parameters but that didn't work.  **What is the best approach to achieve this?**  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide some more details

Comment: For Ex : Cat A --> Sub Cat B --> Sub Cat C --> ... and so on
Category A has Sub Categories B, Sub Categories B has Sub Categories C and it goes on till infinite level.

Comment: How have you exactly tried to change the url by passing parameters?
Via `$stateParams`?

Comment: Yes but for each view it has to create history in browser so that when user taps on back button it has to take previous category

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you might need to create new states dynamically based on the number of subcategories that exist. I'd check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866387/angular-ui-router-programmatically-add-states) about creating states dynamically.

When you fetch all of the subcategories, execute a function to calculate the states based on the number of subcategories.

Edit to add: After you have the states, then you should be able to easily navigate to the child states using a `<ui-sref>` tag. [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

Comment: But every time you load the same state dynamically the controller will be get executed which is not required in my case.