# Angular ui-router: dynamically add states not during config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866387/angular-ui-router-programmatically-add-states), I want to dynamically add ui-router states, but I'm not sure how to do it given the following:

We start with a small set of routes (max 5) that allow the user to navigate the login process: The user logs in (multi step login process), then selects the product type and role they want to use (assuming user has more than one product type/role, else they will bypass this view). At that point, I want to go out to my service and get the list of routes the user has access to, given the userid, product type, & role - I plan to send down an array of data structures that very closely match what is provided to `$stateProvider.state(...)`.

In my app.run.js, I am checking `$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart"` and moving the user along from view to view in the multi-step login process and therefore know when I need to go out to my service to load up the available routes.

When the routes are loaded, I'll probably put a flag in a cookie to indicate that it was properly loaded for this user/product/role.

I don't think a provider really makes sense here since I don't want the routes loaded at config. It feels wrong (not sure why) to call the service to load the routes in the stateChangeStart.

Is this approach a reasonable one?

***Note:*** I also see that there is an [outstanding request](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1095) to be able to remove states from $stateProvider. In the meantime until this request is implemented, how do we clear the $stateProvider of routes (apart from a browser refresh)?

Answer (score 0):

For adding states after the config phase, you should use the Future State functionality in the [`ui-router-extra`](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future) package.

Since there's no official support for deleting routes, you could probably merge in [this PR](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1114) to get something going, but you'd have to add functionality to remove the condition from `urlRouterProvider` as well since that's a bug with that PR.