# What is the best way to set up many routes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, routes

I am creating an web app in AngularJS. The purpose of the app is just a large information based app.

So within the app there are a lot of pages (40+).

Is it possible to create a JSON array of all pages and use that in the routing.

Instead of writing by hand each time:

```
.when('/standards', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/02_core_standards/index.html'
})
```

Or is there an even more efficient way?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25872852/1230663) using ui-router? The other answers to that question are useful too

Comment: You can load routes from json file if you want.