# Angular ui-router with localization in the url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I want to do is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281652/localize-urls-with-ui-router-and-angular-translate)

It allows me to have urls like `domain.com/en/contacts`

But additionally I want the url to have a language code when user navigates to the main page of the webpage by `domain.com` -> `domain.com/en/`

To do so I need to detect user language first and then add {locale} params to the url. Is there a good solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try getting the locale of the user's browser by doing something like

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language
```

in the `.run` [section of your angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation). Depending on the user language, you can then set a factory to store the locale and then use that in the router to redirect the user to the right uri.