# Angular JS routing in multilanguage app is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to implement a multilanguage app.
i need to access the requested language by adding a two letter iso parameter to the URL before the controller name.
for example:
http://appPath/en/home
http://appPath/fr/home
http://appPath/ar/home

```
 $stateProvider
         .state('home', {
             url: '/home',
             templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "home.html",
             controller: 'homeController'
         })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "login.html",
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
      .state('customers', {
          url: '/customers',
          templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "customers.html",
          controller: 'customersController'
      })
      .state('signup', {
          url: '/signup',
          templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "signup.html",
          controller: 'signupController'
      });
```

i'm using a basic stateprovider for routing right now. any idea how to change this to get this feature working?

Thank you in advance,

---

**UPDATE**

---

For anyone having the same problem, my solution was:

changed each state to the following

```
 .state('signup', {
              url: '/:lang/signup',
              templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "signup.html",
              controller: 'signupController',
              resolve: {
                  lang: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
                      document.cookie = "lang=" + $stateParams.lang;
                  }]
              }
          });
```

i save the value of the $stateParams lang into a cookie so you can access it through the app.run() and pass it to my translationService since the $stateParams is not initialized yet there.

this way your app will work only with html5mode=false. which means you will always see an ugly hashtag in the URL (http://path/#/{lang}/{controllername} andto solve this, i configured the $locationProvider this way:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

and set the base url of the site by inserting inside the  tag of your index.html file this line:

```
 <base href="/">
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281652/localize-urls-with-ui-router-and-angular-translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the language code as a url parameter

```
$stateProvider
     .state('home', {
         url: '/:langcode/home',
         templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "home.html",
         controller: 'homeController'
     });
```

And in your controller, get `langcode` value using `$stateParams`

```
$scope.language = $stateParams.langcode;
```

Comment: This is what i did, and ended up with an invalid HTML in the page - duplicate views. to get this fixed i disabled the html5mode. but still, i dont see any content in my view,
i use     <ui-view>    </ui-view> in my index.html file

**UPDATE**: it does not reach the controller while debugging.