# WordPress Inside Magento URL Rewrite Method Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento-1.9, fishpig

This may look like already submitted question. But sure it's not. Before getting into what I need, I tried these ways which found on stack,

1. **.htaccess Method**
2. **vhost Method**
3. **Apache Config Method**

Combining with all above or using individual specified methods. But I couldn't get my requirement. So only I posted this question and here my question.

I have my site like this, magento in root directory and wordpress as wp and the folder structure like this,

```
app/
downloader/
errors/
....
var/
....
wp/
....
index.php
....
```

Now I can access magento and wordpress like this

```
www.store-url.com - Magento
www.store-url.com/wp/blog/ - Wordpress
```

But I need to access like this.

```
www.store-url.com - Magento
www.store-url.com/blog/ - Wordpress
```

So far the solutions I found works correctly upto the `/blog/` but anything after that is not working for me, Like,

```
www.store-url.com/blog/any-identifier-here/
www.store-url.com/blog/any-identifier-here/identifier-2-here/
```

doesn't works for me. I am looking for best rewrite option that enables me to work like above url.

I tried the below but not working,

1. [.htaccess - Wordpress under Magento site with multi language sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613815/htaccess-wordpress-under-magento-site-with-multi-language-sub-directories)
2. [htaccess multi language site with sub directories, and default 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570572/htaccess-multi-language-site-with-sub-directories-and-default-301)
3. [Endless Redirect Loop by htaccess rules multi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474511/endless-redirect-loop-by-htaccess-rules-multi-language)

Please someone help me..
Thanks!